# Facebook Messenger bot, returning multiple messages or payloads

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm looking to return multiple responses to a user. For instance this might be an image and a text block, or a text block and a list.

So far I've not been able to find a way of doing this, everything I try either results in one of the payloads not displaying or it failing completely.

Here's an example of an attempt at displaying a text block and a list:

```
{
    speech:"myMessage",
    displayText:"myMessage",
    data:{
        facebook:{
            "attachment": {
              "type": "template",
              "payload": {
                "template_type": "list",
                "top_element_style": "compact",
                "elements": [
                  {
                    "title": "£10",
                    "image_url": "http://example.com/example.jpg",
                    "subtitle": "An amazing t-shirt"
                  },
                  {
                    "title": "£30",
                    "image_url": "http://example.com/example.jpg",
                    "subtitle": "Another amazing t-shirt"
                  },
                  {
                    "title": "£40",
                    "image_url": "http://example.com/example.jpg",
                    "subtitle": "An amazing t-shirt"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
        }
    },
    contextOut:[],
    source:"webhook"
}
```

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Each message is separate, but you can send a batch request to the graph API to dispatch all the messages with a single API call:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/